# advance z-index with positioning drop-down menu over higher div z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have three divs: header, content, footer

```
<div id="header">
 <ul id="top-nav">
  nav links & sub menus
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
 .. content
</div>

<div id="footer">
 .. footer links
</div>
```

I set content with a larger z-index, and gave it a margin-top:-100px to display part of the content div above the header, as seen in this screenshot (below). I also gave ul#top-nav a larger z-index than #content, but no luck.

[image]

I want to display a drop-down menu when hovering over the links (About, Visit, Volunteer, etc...), but they display behind the content div. I know this happens because the content div has a larger z-index than the header div, but is it possible to display the navigation over the content div when you hover over the links?

Comment: It is possible without any hassle, can you show us your code/fiddle so we can point you to changes... please..

Comment: Can you show the css too.....

Comment: If your content is after the header in the DOM, you won't even need a z-index for it to be displayed on top of the header. It will happen automatically. Anyway, the links are HTML elements too, I presume? You can give them styles as well!

Comment: Yes, for the dom, the order: header,content, footer. I set a higher z-index for the content to display the content above the header w/ margin-top:-100px, I did it this way because it would not display the text until after 100px otherwise.

Comment: Anyway, stupid question, but must your content be on top of the header?

Comment: yes, the content needs to be on top of the header.

Comment: I assume the gold background is part of the `div#header` CSS declaration. Have you tried applying a z-index to `ul#top-nav` which is greater than the z-index on `div#content`?

Comment: @GoranMottram - yes, but that did not work.

Comment: See my answer for your problem, i have created dropdown navigation in fiddle for demonstration and give the content,header, footer different backgroun-color and borders for boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` only works for positioned elements. In this case you don't need to set `z-index` for anything.

Put the menu item and its sub menu in some box. Use a `:hover` rule for it with `position: relative;`.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ghsm/

Answer (score 2):

See the below fiddle if i am getting your problem correct

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvdfD/8/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xvdfD/8/embedded/result/

CSS:

```
    #header
{
    background:#999;
    height:100px;
}

#content {
    background:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top:-98px;
    border:1px solid magenta;
    color:#6F6;
}
#footer {
    background:#999;
    height:100px;
}
ul#navigation-1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    height:21px;
    border-top:1px solid #b9121b;
    border-bottom:1px solid #b9121b;
    font:normal 8pt verdana, arial, helvetica;
}
ul#navigation-1 li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:148px;
}
ul#navigation-1 li a:link, ul#navigation-1 li a:visited {
    padding:4px 0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#b9121b;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:148px;
    height:13px;
}
ul#navigation-1 li:hover a, ul#navigation-1 li a:hover, ul#navigation-1 li a:active {
    padding:4px 0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#ec454e;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:146px;
    height:13px;
    border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
}
ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    display:none;
    background:#ffffff;
    width:146px;
    position:absolute;
    top:21px;
    left:-1px;
    border:1px solid #b9121b;
    border-top:none;
}
ul#navigation-1 li:hover ul.navigation-2 {
    display:block;
}
ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li {
    width:146px;
    clear:left;
    width:146px;
}
ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li a:link, ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li a:visited {
    clear:left;
    background:#b9121b;
    padding:4px 0;
    width:146px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li:hover a, ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li a:active, ul#navigation-1 li ul.navigation-2 li a:hover {
    clear:left;
    background:#ec454e;
    padding:4px 0;
    width:146px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making your "header" a body background image - this way you don't run into z-index issues between navigation or content. Just make the divs as tall as they need to be.

Just put your navigation into the actual header div and style it appropriately.